# How to run code in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

If I go to "tools" and select "python console", and enter several lines of code, how do I execute this? If my cursor is at the end of the script, I can just hit enter. But how can I run the code using keyboard shortcuts if the cursor is not at the end? In Spyder this is done using shift+enter, but I can't figure out how to do it here. I've seen places say control+enter, but that doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: The "Python Console" on PyCharm works basically the same as the standard python interpreter, it executes each line of code after pressing <Enter/Return> unless it's indented inside a code block then it's executed after the next blank line.

Comment: Otherwise, running a script that is open in the editor is default `Shift+F10` (at least that's what it is on the Windows installation I've got), you can probably change it to whatever works best for you

Comment: In the Python Console, hitting enter only runs the code if the cursor is placed at the end of the code. I just don't want to always care about where the cursor is to run the script.

Comment: Oh my bad, now I understand what you mean. While just messing around with it now, I noticed if you're anywhere in a line, hitting `Shift+Enter` then `Enter` again executes that line

Comment: If you enter two lines of code and place the cursor at the end of the first line, using Shift+Enter then Enter works? It doesn't work for me for some reason.

Comment: The initial Shift+Enter just places a blank line between the two code lines

Comment: I guess I'm not able to understand your goal. You want two lines of code on one line to get recognized, parsed, and executed by the console as two lines of code?

Comment: Only way that would work is put a semicolon `;` between each line of code within the same line

Comment: No, sorry I'm not being clear. Open up the Python Console (under "tools"). One one line, type a=1 and on the second line, type b=1, but don't execute the code. Place the cursor after the "1" after a=1, and hit enter. It should just place a blank line between the two. Now do the same, but hit Shift+Enter. It just adds a blank line between the two again. Does that help? I just want to execute a chunk of code without caring where the cursor is placed. Shift+Enter doesn't work for me -- it just adds a blank line in the code.

Comment: Okay I think that is similar to the `a=1b=1` scenario you deleted earlier

Comment: Just write any chunk of code you like. Write it in a text editor and copy it in to the Python Console. Then place the cursor somewhere in the middle, and hit Enter. It won't execute the code, but will simply add a new blank line. Then using Shift+Enter will do the same. It seems like nothing will run the code unless the cursor is at the end of the code.

Comment: Sorry, the a=1b=1 earlier was a mistake so I had to remove it. My last comment is a little clearer.

Comment: No worries, I did as you said, I wrote some lines in a text editor all on one line, copied and pasted it into the Console window, put the cursor somewhere in the middle of the line, hit Enter, but I *didn't get a new blank line*, I got `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` due to not putting semicolons between each of the statements.

Comment: Sorry I'm unable to reproduce your problem. Using semicolons, or Shift+Enter seems to work for all of the scenarios you mention. If you want to continue discussing it, we should move this to a chat, otherwise I should give up because I am not helping you, sorry.

Comment: Okay here you go just try this last one...Go here: http://pastebin.com/9gTmEWqA and highlight the three lines and copy them directly into the Python Console. Place the cursor after the "a=1" line and hit enter and tell me what you see.

Comment: I see `>>> a=1 <newline> b=1 <newline> d=[1,2,3] <blank line> >>> <cursor>`. I did as you instructed (unfortunately I'm on two different computers, so I couldn't directly copy from your code to the PyCharm, but I rewrote it in a text editor and copied/pasted the lines into the Python Console)

Comment: And placing the cursor after a=1 and hitting Enter runs the code?

Comment: well yes, it "runs the code" not outputting anything of course, but if I copy those lines into the Python Console, move the cursor up to the first line after the `a=1`, press Enter, a new interpreter prompt `>>>` appears after the`d=[1,2,3]` and I can then type `a` and it returns `1`, so seems it did "run". As it should because the copied code contains the implicit newlines `'\n'`

Comment: Alright, well thanks a lot for trying. I'm not sure what's going on. Maybe it's the Pycharm IDE version I'm using or something.

Comment: Sure, very welcome, I was happy to try, sorry I couldn't replicate your results. Maybe the version is related, but highly doubtful since the PyCharm Python Console is the standard python terminal with no modifications and just embedded into a GUI. I strongly believe whatever you are trying to do *is* possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Win 10, 64Bits. Run your codes using **Ctrl + Shift + F10** or simply right click on the workspace and click *Run* from the options.

Answer (score 1):

in mac.
you can use **fn+shift+f10** and happy coding with python

Answer (score 0):

From Jetbrains' official [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/creating-and-running-your-first-python-project.html#d56034e399):
PyCharm suggests several ways to run a script opened in the editor:

- First, you can use the keyboard shortcut ⌃⇧R
- Second, you can use the context menu command (here Run Solver), invoked by right-clicking the editor background
- Use the main menu Run | Run, Run | Run 'Solver'
- Finally, it is possible to run a script from the main toolbar, using the temporary run/debug configuration Solver

Comment: This doesn't run the code in the python console (after going to "tools" and select "python console").

Comment: Nothing out of these four worked for me. 
Maybe I should not just open a file but has to create new project and import file into it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project name / select New / select Python File

Pycharm needs to know you're running a Python file before option to run is available