# How to run a program in python using pycharm

Tags: python

I made a program

```
FN=int(raw_input("Enter a number"))
SN = int(raw_input("Enter a number"))
TN = FN+SN
PRINT (TN)
```

Please someone tell me how to run it in pycharm

also the error it showing is :
    Cannot run program "C:\
Users\Lenovo\PyCharmProjects\Untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe"(in directory"C:\Users\Lenovo\PyCharmProjects\untitled"): Create process error = 2. The System cannot find the file specified

Comment: There's a green triangle in the upper-right corner. You can also put your code in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement, and then there'll be a green triangle right next to the line with the `if`. You should click this triangle to run your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42846803/how-to-run-code-in-pycharm

Answer (score 1):

Try to Shift+F10 shortcut, or you can right click to the editor and select `Run( name_of_your_file.py)` section.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I see you solved your problem so I'm here to help you write a clearer code.
I would write it like this:

```py
def summer():

    FN = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    SN = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    TN = FN + SN
    print(TN)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    summer()
```

For instance you wrote `FN=int...` and then `SN = int...`, keep in mind that PEP8 (Python style guide) want you to be consistend throughout your code with the spacing and there should always be a space when you assign a value to a variable.